# AngularJS not working with my html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to build my first AngularJS app but it is not working, i am unable to find the problem why it is not working. It is not showing the name and result of sayHello function on the html page.

This is my js and html file.

```js
(function(){
 // body...
 'use strict';
 angular.module('myFirstApp',[]);

 .controller('myFirstController', function($scope){
  // body...
  $scope.name = "Isha";
  $scope.sayHello = function() {
   // body...
   return "Hello";
  }
 });
})();
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
 <title>My First AngularJS App</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <h1>My First AngularJS App</h1>
 <div ng-app="myFirstApp" ng-controller="myFirstController">
  {{sayHello()}}
  {{name}}
 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you offer a fiddle?

Comment: angular.module('myFirstApp',[]);  remove the  ;  from this line of code

Comment: Remove the semicolon after ```angular.module('myFirstApp',[])```

Comment: Did you not see `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .` in the console? **Eliminate any issues that aren't relevant to the problem.** If your question isn’t about a compiler error, ensure that there are no compile-time errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the ; after the Module,  and add the controller. Otherwise you need to declare as

```
var app = angular.module('myFirstApp',[]);
```

then

```
app.controller('myFirstController', function($scope){
```

**DEMO**

```js
(function(){
 // body...
 'use strict';
 angular.module('myFirstApp',[]).controller('myFirstController', function($scope){
  $scope.name = "Isha";
  $scope.sayHello = function() {
  return "Hello";
  }
 });
})();
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
 <title>My First AngularJS App</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <h1>My First AngularJS App</h1>
 <div ng-app="myFirstApp" ng-controller="myFirstController">
  {{sayHello()}}
  {{name}}
 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a semicolon too much

```js
(function(){
 // body...
 'use strict';
 angular.module('myFirstApp',[]) // <= note I removed the ;

 .controller('myFirstController', function($scope){
  // body...
  $scope.name = "Isha";
  $scope.sayHello = function() {
   // body...
   return "Hello";
  }
 });
})();
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
 <title>My First AngularJS App</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <h1>My First AngularJS App</h1>
 <div ng-app="myFirstApp" ng-controller="myFirstController">
  {{sayHello()}}
  {{name}}
 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the semi-colon after:

```
angular.module('myFirstApp',[]); // <-- Remove this semi-colon
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by two ways:

**1: Assign your module in a variable**

```
var app = angular.module('myFirstApp',[]);

    app.controller('myFirstController', function($scope){
        // body...
    });
```

**2: You can directly take the reference of your module in your controller**

```
 angular.module('myFirstApp',[])
       .controller('myFirstController', function($scope){
        //body.....
    });
```